# How to load Desktop View (In DeviceFamily-Desktop) on Mobile device in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-desktop

I have two View (Xaml) in my UWP App, One View is under a folder named **DeviceFamily-Desktop** *(which can loaded in Desktop device)* and another view is  under a folder named **DeviceFamily-Mobile** similar to Desktop but that can be loaded in Mobile Device.

These view can be loaded and rendered based on Device family as per its functionality.

My requirement is How can I load the Mobile View *(which is under  DeviceFamily-Mobile folder)*  in Desktop Device?

Comment: why would you want to do that? for testing?